# Using yargs in *one* gulp task applies it in *all* tasks: Why? How to fix?

Tags: node.js, gulp, yeoman-generator, yargs

I've got a UI project, with an automation workflow based on [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). I added `gulp-ng-config`, in order to perform builds differently based on an environment variable. I use the package 'yargs' to extract the environment flag, and make it available to that task. But even though the task should be encapsulated, my use of yargs to create requirements for it is now active on all gulp tasks in my whole project.

Here's the gulp task for `ngconfig`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var conf = require('./conf');
var gulpNgConfig = require('gulp-ng-config');
var argv = require('yargs')
  .usage('This `build` or `serve` task includes an ngConfig task, whose requirements have not been met via arguments. \n LONG USAGE: <command> --environment <"production" or "sit" or "local">.\n SHORT USAGE <command> -e <"production" or "sit" or "local">')
  .epilogue('For more information, see the iJoin client README.')
  .demand(['e'])
  .alias('e', 'environment')
  .argv;

gulp.task('ngconfig', function() {
  // default config:
  var thisConfig = {
    environment: argv.environment,
    wrap: "(function () { \n 'use strict'; \n return <%= module %> \n })();"
  };

  gulp.src('gulp/server-config.json')
    .pipe(gulpNgConfig('ijoin.apiConfig', thisConfig))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/prebuild')));

});
```

And it's invoked as part of `build`, here:

```
gulp.task('build', ['ngconfig', 'html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

When we want to perform a build with our environment variable, we execute

```
gulp build -e local
```

And, it's all working fine! But it's spilling over into my other tasks. For instance, when I start up my local API mock server, with:

```
gulp stubby
```

It complains that I haven't included the necessary args:

```
This `build` or `serve` task includes an ngConfig task, whose requirements have not 
been met via arguments.
 LONG USAGE: <command> --environment <"production" or "sit" or "local">.
 SHORT USAGE <command> -e <"production" or "sit" or "local">

Options:
  -e, --environment                                                   [required]

For more information, see the iJoin client README.

Missing required arguments: e
```

But my intent was that those necessary args are required only on the `ngconfig` task. (`ngconfig` is definitely not a dependency of `stubby`.) So, why the spill-over into other tasks, and how do I fix it?

Comment: try moving definition of `argv` inside the ngconfig task

Comment: <smacks forehead> Yes. That's it. Thank you. Care to post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the argv variable is added outside of scope of `ngconfig` it will impact other taks execution as well.

please move it inside the `ngconfig` task